# FBX Export: How to merge animations of two different objects with both a different armature?

Tags: animation, export, unity

I have a problem, I modelled and rigged a gun inside of Blender. Then merged it with some hands that were already rigged. I animated them inside of Blender with the Dope Sheet on Action mode.
To have them play the same animation together, I need to select both armatures and select the same animation and press play. If I only select one armature and change the 'action' they both play a different action.
This Is not the biggest problem.
I want to import my model and animation to Unity, I use FBX to do that since it is the best possible option. Now to clarify some extra things, I have made 2 animations. One for firing, the other for idle.
Exporting it to FBX and importing it inside of Unity, gives me 4 animations.

[image]

I can not animate them correctly this way, since Unity doesn't allow for 2 animations to be played at the same time. (Well they do, but this requires a lot of extra trickery to get it right. Since I'm also blending the animation for it to look smooth.)
How do I get Blender to get the animations together into one?
I've thought about not using the action editor and just animating one after another and splitting it inside of Unity. But I think that would generate two animations instead of one. How would I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could join the armatures